# Creating a responsive triangle with repeating background image

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, css-shapes

I am trying to create a triangle for a website, that maintains 100% width at all times as well as having a repeating background and to overlay a dynamic background. Happy to use any method, so far have tried using SVG with a pattern, with no success.

Also tried border with borderimage, but again with no success.

I should mention this will be overlaying an image, so with a triangular half a rectangle is using the repeating image, the other half needs to be transparent.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how this may be done, or experienced it in the past?

**EDIT**

Example: [image]

Those are 1px x 2px black lines in 3px x 3px squares.

Comment: Can you put up an image of what you have in mind?

Comment: hi jcuenod, I have added an image, and a quick description.

Comment: Is that one div containing 4 images or just one image?

Comment: This is going to be used site-wide, that is just an example of it overlaying 4 images, in other places it will overlay colour, and in others just one image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a rotated container with overflow hidden.
This will allow you to display those images over an other image a gradient or any other non plain background :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/u8z7aa2f/4/)**

```css
.wrap {
    transform-origin:0 100%;
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding-right:5%;
}
.images {
    transform-origin:inherit;
    transform:rotate(3deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /** <-- to prevent diagonal line aliasing in chrome **/
}
img {
    float:left;
    width:24%;
    margin:0 .5%;
}

/** FOR THE DEMO **/
body{background:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg');background-size:cover;overflow-x:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-200-9.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-200-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-200-6.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-200-1.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the solution we've chosen to go with, if you were interested to see the implementation its here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPgmRL

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pseudo element for this in order to overlap your images:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150vw;
  height: 40vw;
  bottom: -30vw;
  left: -25vw;
  background: #222;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: nice use of pseudo element

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pseudo element which can receive a background image.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* quick clearfix */
}
.wrapper::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 150%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.wrapper img {
  max-width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Having read the question (more thoroughly, this time), OP is looking to have an image background as well, so it seems that pseudo's wouldn't be the best option here

Comment: Why can't the pseudo element have background image? I just used a color here as an example.

Comment: Sorry, it's not that, It's OP seems to want to have a large image behind this (see web-tiki's answer) it seems